# Is There A Way To Find End Ships Quickly Without Using Cheats?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

So I had successfully killed the Ender Dragon. I used the ender pearls and threw them in those small portal things. I had found a few end cities, but no ships. Is there a way so that we could find them more quickly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every single end city has a fixed chance to spawn with a ship. Sadly the only things that you can use without using any external tools is the way the cities themselves spawn.

Since most of the time they spawn kind of in a line. So once you have found one city you should try going going along the axes of the world. Meaning you should go strictly north, east, south or west. very often you will find an end city within a few hundred blocks of distance.

There are tools you can use to look up where the cities are (i.e. chuckbase end city finder) but there is no simple way to finde ships specifically.

Comment: Chunkbase end city finder has an icon on where the end cities are showing whether the city has a ship or not.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do this without cheats unfortunately

Answer (score -2):

well you could copy the world and then go to creative mode and put in chat "/locate end_city_ship
then it will say the cords then you take down the cords on a notepad or something then delete the copy of the world then go to your original world and go to the end through the end portal and go to the coordinates that you took down
this is a method but it could be classified as cheating

Comment: Using creative mode sounds like using cheats.